# Change Unity terrain resolution without losing the terrain

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a really complex terrain in Unity, its full of trees, grass, flowers etc.

When I run the game, the frame rate is really low, maybe 1 to 3 fps.

I read some where that the terrain resolution may be the problem since i got it cranked up high.

When I try to lower the terrain resolution, unity erases the whole terrain, which is bad since I can go spending two months to remake it all over again.

Does anybody know of a way to change the resolution of the terrain, and other terrain parameters without losing the whole terrain?

Maybe there is a script in the unity asset store that can export the terrain and lower the resolution, and re-import it, or something like that?

Anybody know of script or method to do that? I don't have time to develop a script myself, or spend huge amount of time on this.

Comment: I know this is too broad but probably worth mentioning: you could use `Terrain.activeTerrain.terrainData.GetHeights()` in editor script to save data in a file or something. then change resolution of your terrain and use `Terrain.activeTerrain.terrainData.SetHeights()` and use every other value in the saved file or something in-between...

Comment: does it help?  http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/658185/view.html ... http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/830867/view.html

Answer (score 0):

I know one thing you can do is decreasing the resolution of the texture you used for terrain and grasees or trees on it.

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do is very complex and will take a lot of time. An alternative way of getting higher FPS is to select all your non-moving objects, or just the prefabs in your prefabs folder and check Static in the right-hand corner of the inspector. This will boost your FPS but if you have a day-night cycle you should uncheck Lightmap Static by pressing the downwards arrow next to the Static button in the inspector.

Comment: That wasn't the question